# How can I override a Swift delegate method to take more parameters?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a form with 3 UITextFields. I'd like to validate the user input for each field, when the user is done inputing text in that specific field. Right now, I've got a method

```
validateAllFields()
```

that I call in:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    self.validateAllFields()
}
```

I'd rather validate a single field, after its text has been modified, not validate all fields after each one has been modified.

Is there a ways to override a delegate method or extend UITextField to take more parameters? Something like:

```
override func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField,
                       textFieldIdentifier: TextFieldIdentifierEnum) {
    self.validate(textField: textField, basedOn: textFieldIdentifier)
}
```

I suspect it can be done with an extension, but I'm unclear how to proceed.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can't add more parameters. And there is no need. You are already told which text field is affected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to as the paramter `(_ textField: UITextField)` gives you the current textfield the user changes

Suppose you have

```
@IBOutlet weak var emailTexf:UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passTexf:UITextField!
```

---

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
  self.validateAllFields(textField)
}
fun validateAllFields(_ current:UITextField) {

   if  emailTexf == current {

   }
   else if passTexf == current {

   } 
   else {  }  // etc
}
```

Comment: Sure, that makes sense. How do I distinguish them? In your example, you use "emailTexf" and "passTexf", but where are you getting those from? Happy to upvote and select this as the answer, if you can help me clarify that. Thanks!

Comment: you need to replace them with your own variables , above is for an example

Comment: Can you give a more complete example that explains what you're saying? Sorry, I'm not understanding. Thank you!

Comment: It's supposed you have outlets for the textfields to validate see edit